# complex differential geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, several-complex-variables

I recently asked a question in my mathematical physics class:
In complex manifolds, why don't we combine the real part of one variable with the imaginary part of the other variable to obtain more general CR-equations?
My lectures mentioned something about conformal manifolds. But I didn't understand quite what he was talking about. Could you please refer me to literature which deals with the question that I put?
I haven't read any literature on Functions of Several Complex Variables, but I could imagine that they the CR equations could look something like this:
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial y_j}$$
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y_i}=-\frac{\partial v}{\partial x_j}$$
where i and j are natural numbers and run from 1 to dimension of the complex space.

thank you

Comment: What exactly are you proposing (write the equations you have in mind)?

Comment: @MoisheCohen I edited the question.

Comment: Your equation is more or less the general CR equation (where you should have $i=j$ and $z_i  = x_i + \sqrt{-1} y_i$ are the complex coordinates).

Comment: I know that usually i=j. but the whole point is that why should we consider only the case where i=j? Why not combine the real and imaginary parts of different complex variables?

Comment: It is not exactly clear what you are proposing: Are you asking what happens if you have these equations **for all** $i, j$ or only for **some** $i, j$? If you mean, for all $i, j$ then your function simply becomes a holomorphic function of the form $f(z, z + a_2, z+ a_3,..., z+ a_n)$ for some complex numbers $a_2,..., a_n$.

Comment: @user139383: Because you're studying functions on $\Bbb C^n$, and this requires $n$ complex coordinates $z_j=x_j+\sqrt{-1}y_j$.

Answer (score 0):

Choose your favorite complex manifold.  In differential geometry, there is often a source manifold (call it a domain if you like) and a target manifold (call it the image of the pre-image domain, or if you like, the range of a map from a source to target).  Conformal simply means angles in the pre-image of the map are preserved in the target under the conformal map.

I found Theodore W. Gamelin, "Complex Analysis," Springer, 2001, page 59 helpful as it illustrates with a picture a conformal map.

For the most part, I believe John Ma is giving you good advice.